# unable to find node on an unmounted component

Tags: node.js, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOAVD.png)

I do have a login screen. After logging to the dashboard all functionalities are working. but when I just try to click icons in dashboard the page becomes blank even before clicking (on focusing itself page becomes empty). on console the error (unable to find node on an unmounted component) is notified repeatedly

Comment: Please add a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to explain the issue  better.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.